# Close putty connection from CentOS 6 shell script

Tags: ssh, shell, centos6, dracut

as title says I have a centOS 6 machine which uses an dracut, initramfs preboot ssh. I want to create a shell script that at the end of it's execution it closes the console and ssh connection. How can I do that. Escape character ~. does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to determine PID of shell started after SSH-session has been established - and kill it. SSH session terminates automatically.
Most shells has variable $$ that contains PID of parent shell. So just add to your script last line:

```
kill -6 $$
```